# PHP foreach solo trae el último resultado en AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, json

Estoy queriendo imprimir en un carrusel varios teléfonos que tengo almacenados en la BD. Actualmente esos teléfonos los tengo "quemados" y quiero empezar a obtenerlos desde la BD, hacerlo dinámico en otras palabras.

Mi problema es que los estoy obteniendo mediante un foreach, y, si el foreach lo pruebo SIN usar AJAX, funciona bien, me trae todos los resultados que tengo en mi consulta. Pero si lo uso con AJAX, únicamente me trae el último resultado.

Alguien de casualidad ve algo que yo no? Sugerencias por favor jaja:(

Este es el PHP:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT p.id, pl.plan, m.marca, e.id AS 'equipo_id', e.nombre_equipo, e.pantalla, e.procesador, e.ram, e.camara_trasera, e.camara_frontal, e.ruta, 
p.precio, p.prima FROM precios AS p 
INNER JOIN planes AS pl ON p.id_plan = pl.id 
INNER JOIN equipos AS e ON p.id_equipo = e.id
INNER JOIN marcas AS m ON e.id_marca = m.id");

        foreach($result as $row_comparte)
        {
            $nombre_equipo = $row_comparte['nombre_equipo'];
            $id_equipo = $row_comparte['equipo_id'];
            $ruta = $row_comparte['ruta'];
            $precio = $row_comparte['precio'];
            $prima = $row_comparte['prima'];
            $precio_sin_punto = str_replace(".00", "", "$precio");
            $prima_sin_punto = str_replace(".00", "", "$prima");

                $output='
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-content cardsita">
                        <span class="card-title for-checkbox-tools center" style="height: 75px;">'.$nombre_equipo.'</span>
                        <input type="hidden" class="titulo_plan" value="'.$plan_comparte.'">
                        <a class="modal-trigger" href="#'.$id_equipo.'">
                            <div class="contenedor_imagen">
                                <img src="'.$ruta.'" alt="'.$nombre_equipo.'" width="100%">
                                <div class="centrado"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 12px;">&#xe913</i> Ver detalles</div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="center" style="padding: 20px 0px 15px 0px;">
                            <a href="#factura"><button class="btn waves-effect purple waves-light checkbox-tools addToCart" value="'.$precio.'">Cotizar</button></a>
                        </div>
                        <p class="center bold movistarmorado" style="font-size: 30px;">$'.$precio_sin_punto.'</p>
                        <p class="light center movistarmorado">+ $'.$prima_sin_punto.' prima</p>
                        <input type="hidden" class="prima" value="'.$prima.'"/>
                        <input type="hidden" class="modal_id" value="'.$id_equipo.'"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ';
        }

        echo json_encode($output);
```

Y este es el código del AJAX:

```
<script>
        $('input[type=radio][name=presupuesto_equipo]').on('change', function() {
            var equipo = this.value;
            consultar_equipo(equipo);
        });
        
        function consultar_equipo(equipo)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"../ajax/consultar_equipo.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{equipo:equipo},
                dataType:"JSON",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#respuesta_equipo').html(data);
                    $.getScript("../../js/carousel.js");
                },
                error: function(data) {
               
                console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: No estas concatenando el HTML sino que siempre estas pisando el valor de la variable `$output`. Solo tenes que cambiar `$output =` por  `$output .= `. Más info [Operadores para strings](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: Hola @Marcos! Probé hacer lo que me dijiste pero me retorna como si la variable no se difiniera. Así: "Undefined variable: output2"

Comment: Tienes que definir `$output` antes del `foreach`  como una variable vacía, y dentro del bucle ir concatenando. Algo así: `$output=""; foreach (...) { $output . = "<div class="...." aquí todo lo que tienes </di>"; }`